# Merge two dict in separate list by id

Tags: python, python-2.x, hash-map

I have following data structure

```
>>> a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]
>>> b = [{'id': 1, 'age': 12}, {'id': 2, 'age': 21}]
```

I want to merge the dictionaries present in list **b** with list **a** by matching id. (`a` and `b` have the same number of entries, but the order can be different.)
So I want following:

```
[{'age': 12, 'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'age': 21, 'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]
```

I am doing it by following:

```
>>> for ta in a: 
...   for tb in b:
...     if ta['id'] == tb['id']:
...       ta.update(tb)
... 
>>> a
[{'age': 12, 'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'age': 21, 'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]
>>>
```

Is there a better Pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Can entries in two lists `a` and `b` come in an arbitrary order? Are the list lengths the same? Please come up with a richer example to more clearly illustrate the desired behaviour.

Comment: a and b list lengths are always same but the order can be different.

Comment: I'm curious — where do the data for `a` and `b` come from? An SQL database? A CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that no ids are missing in either list, you can just sort the lists by id, and then zip and merge. To sort by id, you can do:

```
import operator
sorting_key = operator.itemgetter("id")
a = sorted(a, key=sorting_key)
b = sorted(b, key=sorting_key)
```

Then, you can go though and update as you were doing before:

```
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    i.update(j)
```

Making your final code:

```
import operator
sorting_key = operator.itemgetter("id")
for i, j in zip(sorted(a, key=sorting_key), sorted(b, key=sorting_key)):
    i.update(j)
```

`a` will then be `[{'name': 'a', 'age': 12, 'id': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 21, 'id': 2}]`. Note that this can be condensed into one line (excluding the import), but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
[i.update(j) for i, j in zip(sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter("id")), sorted(b, key=operator.itemgetter("id")))]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are saying

> I want to merge the dictionary present

but what makes your task a bit difficult is that you are not handling dictonnaries but lists. Among other things, if you keep that idea that way, you'll have to iterate over `n*m` pairs `(ta, tb)` (where `n` and `m` are respective size of `a` and `b`).

A probably better idea would be to reorganise data in `a` and `b` to have them as an actual dict mapping `id` to some additional information. Then, merging will go through maximum `n + m` elements.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical response is to make an `id → dictionary` mapping to remove the inner loop. This has two cases.

Firstly, if you just want to update `a` with the values in `b`, use

```
id_to_a = {dict_['id']: dict_ for dict_ in a}

for dict_ in b:
    id_to_a[dict_['id']].update(dict_)
```

If you want to support a more general case such as an n-way merge, use

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_by_key(dicts, key):
    merged = defaultdict(dict)

    for dict_ in dicts:
        merged[dict_[key]].update(dict_)

    return merged.values()

merge_by_key(chain(a, b), 'id')
#>>> dict_values([{'name': 'a', 'age': 12, 'id': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 21, 'id': 2}])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for d in a:
    result[d['id']].update(d)
for d in b:
    result[d['id']].update(d)
```

And you'd then be left with a dictionary of dictionaries grouped by id. You could finally do:

```
 result.values()
```

To get all merged dicts. This doesn't required sorting, so I believe it should be faster than the accepted answer.